# Como puedo saber cuales están Check AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Quiero extraer el `código` de los `items` `check` pero no se como hacerlo, e intentado pero esto es lo que tengo, ahora mismo tengo una variable donde almaceno todos los `codigos` de cada `item`, pero la idea es almacenar en una variable los codigos de cada `item` seleccionados, tengo el siguiente código.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.materies = [{
       "Codigo": 1,
       "Nombre": "Matematicas"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 2,
       "Nombre": "Fisica"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 3,
       "Nombre": "Espanol"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 4,
       "Nombre": "Etica"
    }]

    $scope.sendCode = function() {
        $scope.codeMaterie = "";
        if ($scope.materies.length){
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.materies.length ; i++) {
                $scope.codeMaterie += $scope.materies[i].Codigo + ";";
            }
        }
    }

});
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US">
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl1" ng-app="app">
    <label ng-repeat="materie in materies">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mat"> {{materie.Nombre}}
    </label>
    <button ng-click="sendCode()">Enviar Code</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como lo tienes puesto ahora, lo que haces es recorrer el listado de valores que usas para crear los `input`, entonces el valor siempre será el mismo: `1;2;3;4;` (la concatenación de todos los valores) en lugar de los valores seleccionados.

Una cosa que puedes hacer es cambiar un poco el HTML para añadir el código como valor del `input` añadiéndole esto: `value="{{materie.Codigo}}"`. Y después en la función `sendCode` en lugar de leer el array de valores, lo que harías sería seleccionar los checkboxes que estén marcados. Algo que puedes hacer así:

```
// seleccionas los checkboxes que se hayan marcado
var ms = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
// concatenamos los valores en la cadena
for (var x = 0; x < ms.length; x++) {
  $scope.codeMaterie += ms[x].value + ";";
}
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.materies = [{
       "Codigo": 1,
       "Nombre": "Matematicas"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 2,
       "Nombre": "Fisica"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 3,
       "Nombre": "Espanol"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 4,
       "Nombre": "Etica"
    }]

    $scope.sendCode = function() {
        $scope.codeMaterie = "";
        if ($scope.materies.length){
            // seleccionas los checkboxes que se hayan marcado
            var materiesSeleccionadas = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
            // concatenamos los valores en la cadena
            for (var x = 0; x < materiesSeleccionadas.length; x++) {
              $scope.codeMaterie += materiesSeleccionadas[x].value + ";";
            }
            
            console.log($scope.codeMaterie);
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US">
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl1" ng-app="app">
    <label ng-repeat="materie in materies">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mat" value="{{materie.Codigo}}"> {{materie.Nombre}}
    </label>
    <button ng-click="sendCode()">Enviar Code</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es ejecutar un change por cada vez que se cambia el valor del checkbox y cambiar según sea el caso el valor de una propiedad en el objeto específico, al final al recorrer el objeto simplemente preguntas por los que están con estado seleccionado en true y listo, todo bajo la misma lógica que estabas implementando.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.materies = [{
       "Codigo": 1,
       "Nombre": "Matematicas"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 2,
       "Nombre": "Fisica"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 3,
       "Nombre": "Espanol"
    }, {
       "Codigo": 4,
       "Nombre": "Etica"
    }];
    
    $scope.cambio = function(materie, valor){
       materie.seleccionado = valor ? true : false;
    }

    $scope.sendCode = function() {
        $scope.codeMaterie = "";
        if ($scope.materies.length){
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.materies.length ; i++) {
              if($scope.materies[i].seleccionado){
                $scope.codeMaterie += $scope.materies[i].Codigo + ";"; 
              }
            }
            
            console.log($scope.codeMaterie);
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US">
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl1" ng-app="app">
    <label ng-repeat="materie in materies">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mat" ng-change="cambio(materie, mat)"> {{materie.Nombre}}
    </label>
    <button ng-click="sendCode()">Enviar Code</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo tomando los valores del checkbox como el código y `0` en caso de no estar checkeado usando `ng-true-value=""` y `ng-false-value=""` de angular.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.mat = [];
  $scope.materies = [
    {
      Codigo: 1,
      Nombre: "Matematicas"
    },
    {
      Codigo: 2,
      Nombre: "Fisica"
    },
    {
      Codigo: 3,
      Nombre: "Espanol"
    },
    {
      Codigo: 4,
      Nombre: "Etica"
    }
  ];

  $scope.sendCode = function() {
    $scope.codeMaterie = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mat.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.mat[i] > 0) {
        $scope.codeMaterie += $scope.materies[i].Codigo + ";";
      }
    }
    
    console.log($scope.codeMaterie);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl1" ng-app="app">
  <label ng-repeat="materie in materies">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mat[$index]" ng-init="mat[$index] = 0" ng-true-value="{{materie.Codigo}}" ng-false-value="0" /> {{materie.Nombre}}
  </label>
  <button ng-click="sendCode()">Enviar Code</button>
</body>
</html>
```